# C# Finding 3 largest values in a 2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Currently, I have a 2D array that is already assigned with random values. I know how to find the largest values with something like this:

```
public static int Largest( int[,] C)
{
    int largest = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < C.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < C.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            if( largest < C[ row, col])
            {
                largest = C[ row, col];
            }
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

But I want to find the three largest values and return the sum. I don't necessarily have any restrictions in how I find it, but is it going to be another method similar to the Largest method I wrote?

Comment: you could sort the array and just use the top 3 values

Answer (score 5):

In C# you have linq which can do this in a breeze:

```
var sum = C.Cast<int>().OrderByDescending(i => i).Take(3).Sum();
```

And that's all, it converts the array to a one-dimensional enumerable, orders it from biggest to smalles, takes the first three elements and sums them.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, potentially faster, definitely less flexible solution than a LINQ based solution:

```
public static int LargestSum(int[,] array)
{
    int firstLargest = 0, secondLargest = 0, thirdLargest = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            int value = array[x, y];
            if(value > thirdLargest)
            {
                if (value > secondLargest)
                {
                    if (value > firstLargest)
                    {
                        thirdLargest = secondLargest;
                        secondLargest = firstLargest;
                        firstLargest = value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        thirdLargest = secondLargest;
                        secondLargest = value;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    thirdLargest = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return firstLargest + secondLargest + thirdLargest;
}
```